# Heroku login error with mysql and git

Tags: mysql, git, heroku

Trying to install correctly heroku.

Problems:
2 times it gives me an error from cmd that MySQL is not internal or external command
Then it write me that I have to install git, that is installed certainly!
I searched that people solved MySQL problem by changing PATH in Env. variables.
For me it doesn't work. reinstalled git, but it doesn't help. There was an advice  remove and install one more time MySQL, only this not yet attempted.

Please, help.

Comment: What is your OS? Have you checked that MySQL client installed correctly? How did you installed git? is location of git.exe in you PATH environment variable?

Comment: OS Windows 8.1, 64-bit.
All vars and pathes checked twice and correct.
What do you mean under question about way of git installation? It works properly when I use not with heroku.

Comment: Could you show what commands did you enter and what is output. and for instance what is output of `heroku create`?

Comment: heroku create gives me following output:
    `"MySQL" is not recognised bla-bla-bla` (x2)
    `Creating app... done, stack is cedar-14`
then two links